# execute a batch file (psexec.exe) from R console

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd, redis, psexec

I am running a redis server to expand the amount of cores for machine learning algorithms.  To create workers on another computer I need to execute a batch file that starts them up on a networked computer.  I can start them on my local machine and get them running on the remote machine through psexec.exe command in a .bat file.  However I also need to be able to invoke this .bat file from my R console to make it an all in one system so I do not have to start them manually every time I run a new model.

when I run a system(command) in R console to start the .bat file I get an error:

```
'PsExec.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning message:
running command 'C:\remoterun.bat' had status 1
```

my system command invoked is:

```
system("C:\\remoterun.bat")
```

Is it possible to execute the .bat file in R to run outside of R?  Is there another cmd type command that I can run that will do the same as psexec that I can run in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the path to PSEXEC defined in your batch file?

Comment: no, it is just PsExec.exe \\remoteIpAddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the PsExec.exe path isn't defined inside the bat file. You could add the PsExec.exe path to your windows path. Have a look here for help on windows paths: http://www.computerhope.com/pathhlp.htm
You could also have a look at the shell() command, something like the below for a test.

```
res <- shell("date /T", intern=TRUE)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `shell` is Linux, not Windows, but [tag:cmd] and [tag:batch-file] both are Windows-specific...

Comment: That did it, Thank you!  I was missing the psexec in the environmentals path

Comment: @CooperBuckeye05, you could of just included the whole path in the batch file.